# replace .permitAll() method with a method that can provide access to only USER and COMP roles

Tags: spring-security

I want to replace .permitAll() method with a method that can provide access to only USER and COMP roles

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/success/**").permitAll() //instead of .permiitAll() I want to define access only for "USER" and "COMP" roles
        .antMatchers("/userProfileHomePage/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/companyHome/**").access("hasRole('COMP')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/success").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf()
        .disable().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error");
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the expected versus actual result?

Comment: `.antMatchers("/success/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "COMP")`

Comment: @Ritesh: when i have used:-
.antMatchers("/success/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "COMP")
got 404 error for Success Url

Comment: At console i got this message:
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Comment: Can you check (or share code) to see how you are assigning roles to users? You might need to use 'ROLE_USER' or 'ROLE_COMP' as role name or use 'hasAnyAuthority' instead of 'hasAnyRole'.